# Sectioned bibliography not working in Lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am trying to get a sectioned bibliography in my thesis, with "References" being the cited articles, and "bibliography" containing additional uncited references. I've followed to the letter the instructions in section 3.1.2 of the Additional Features help file. It should just be a question of ticking the box "sectioned bibliography" and adding the second bibliography. However I get the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'NAT@ctr' defined.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibitemlist} on input line 2 ended by \end{thebibliogr
! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 2 ended by \end{btSect}.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{btSect} on input line 7681 ended by \end{document}.
```

Could anybody shed some light as to what's happening here?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the Latex source that Lyx generates for your file?

Comment: @CharlesStewart relevant latex source is uploaded here <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-g0Q_2MSjVaZ0RJb2E2UFhnQ2M/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: This looks like it might be an error with the tocbibind package.  Try compiling your Latex file with line 64 changed from '\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}' to '\usepackage{tocbibind}'.  Does it still compile?  I'm away from Berlin for the next two weeks, and I will be able to respond faster to email than tex.sx, so if you need help quickly, try contacting me via one of the methods I describe at http://www.textproof.com/send-message.html